# Why can't I use reduce in an array that resulted from a jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reduce

I have a form that I get with `$('#formId')` using jquery. This gives me an array of inputs elements in which I would like to use `Array.prototype.reduce` but apparently I can't. Why is that? Isn't the array returned by the jquery selector a "normal" array? And why I can use other `Array.prototype` methods like `map`, or `filter` and not `reduce`. Can anyone explain me the logic here?

Comment: Duplicate tl;dr: it's not an array. jQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) methods are not Array.prototype methods.

Comment: can use `get()` to return a real array

Comment: I though that the jquery returned a normal array. didn't know about the 'wrapped set'. Thanks for pointing me to answer that explains it. Couldn't find it before.